# The voice Over reads the Label's text twice

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm working on making my app accessible for blind people by using the Voice over.

I have  tableView that contains custom cell with 4 UILabel and Custom HeaderView that has one UILabel as well.

My issue that the voice over reads the UIlabel's text twice every time i tap on any label in the custom cell or the custom header.

Has anyone have this issue?

Comment: hi @shady, how are calling your 'text reading' method when tap on label?

Comment: @nikdange_me You can just set the accessibilityLabel and turn on the Voice Over

Comment: Anyways my issue was that i was adding an UILabel extension before that was setting the accessibilityValue for all labels.

Comment: `accessibilityValue ` is something which should be used to indicate a count or something similar. For ex, if you scroll in a paginated scroll view it announces `label` followed by a pause and then announces `page 1 of 3`.

Answer (score 3):

Anyways my issue was that, I had UILabel extension that was setting the accessibilityValue for all labels by default .

And I was setting the accessibilityValue and accessibilityIdentifier for every label again whenever i use them.

That  made the voice over to be reading out the labels twice.